# How do I set standard behavior for common shortcuts in Cinnamon?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, desktop-shortcuts

I use the Cinnamon desktop environment, but shortcuts  like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for opening the Terminal or <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> for Print Screen don't work.

How can I set these two shortcuts in the Cinnamon desktop environment and other, but these two are the most important for me?

Versions of my software:

- Debian 9.8 (x86-64)
- Cinnamon 3.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my system it looks like this:

**Applicatios** *(the Start Menu)* **-> Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts** *tab* **-> Add** *button*

And in *command input* we could to put this:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -fs '/home/user_name/Images'
```

command.

For another options look at a `xfce4-screenshooter` [via comand line](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/screenshooter/usage#via_command-line) section.

Answer (score 1):

(From the Cinnamon menu) **Preferences** --> **Keyboard**, then click the **Shortcuts** tab.

Comment: Thank you @ajgringo619, it was simpler than I thought :)